# How to remove trailing line-feed character while exploding

Tags: php, explode

I have a plain text file with many lines. Each line contains 5 words exactly. Eg:

```
cat bat rat mat sat
hello hi howdy namaste salaam
here there where nowhere somewhere
a b c d e
......
......
```

Now I am retrieving the lines one by one using `fgets()` function. The lines are retrieved perfectly, but when i `explode` the string to form an array of the 5 words, i see that the trailing `line feed` character is also included in the array.

So **how to remove the trailing `line feed` character while exploding?**

Comment: Is it added to the last element, so that you'd have `sat\n` for the first line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you get the lines use [rtrim](http://php.net/function.rtrim)

```
rtrim($myline, "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`stream_get_line`](http://php.net/function.stream-get-line) which removes the specified line ending.

Comment: can you please give me the link?

Answer (score 1):

rtrim($myline) is even shorter.

As stated in http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php:

Without the second parameter, rtrim() will strip these characters:
" ", an ordinary space.
"\t", a tab.
"\n", a new line (line feed).
"\r", a carriage return.
"\0", the NULL-byte.
"\x0B", a vertical tab.